# I have difficulty in understanding this sentence: even more so

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have difficulty in understanding the following sentence :

> As surprising as the recent financial crisis and recession were, the behavior of the world’s industrialized economies and financial markets during the recovery has been **even more so**.

Does that mean :

> As surprising as the recent financial crisis and recession were, the behavior of the world's industrialized economies and financial markets during the recovery has been **even more surprising**

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. The sentence has the following structure:

> As surprising as (X) were, (Y) has been even more so.

'*Surprising*' is the common quality of X and Y under consideration.

Comment: thank you, one more question, why is it 'were', not 'are'?

The recent financial crisis and recession are surprisng, and the behavior ... has been even more so.

Comment: In this case, I think it's simply because the author considered the surprise to have 'happened' in the past, at the time of the events, rather than now, during the analysis of those events.

Comment: Replying to your "one more question" ... Because the global financial crisis (GFC) and recession were in the **past** while the subsequent behaviour is **continuing** (i.e. the behaviour in question began after the GFC and continues to the present time).  You can also split your original sentence into two, in order to understand the tenses more clearly.  "1.  The recent financial crisis and recession **were surprising**."  "2.  The behaviour of the world's economies [following the GFC and continuing into the present ]... **has been** surprising as well."